# getAsync("Text") vs getAsync("text", cancellationToken)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am using the oneDrive API aka Live SDK. using c# and XAML you can issue http GET request using the above mentioned method like so:

case A:

```
public async void methodA()
{

    try
    {
       var meResult = await connectClient.GetAsync("me"); 
    }
     catch(Exception ex)
    {
    //exception handling
    }

    doSomething();
  }
```

Case B:

```
public async void methodB()
{
    try
    {
        var meResult = await connectClient.GetAsync("me", token);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    //exception handling
    }

    doSomething();
}
```

where `token` is cancellationToken; that will wait for specific time and then cancel the request.

if there is no internet connection:

In case A the `methodA()` will hang on the getAsync and never progress so the `doSomething()` method is never called.

In case B the `methodB()` will handle the exception when the cancellationToken cancel the call then  progress to the `doSomething()` method.

Now my concern and my question is:
  I am afraid that keeping the await call hanging there will mean locking one thread and will affect the performance especially if the user clicked the button many times to call the `methodA()`.

Is my concern justified?
is there a way for the .NET runtime to know that this awaited operation is timed out?? and eventually cancel it?

Comment: You shouldn't be using an `async void` method here.

Comment: Can you elaborate why?

Comment: Because it prohibits the caller from knowing when the method completes, and whether it is successful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass in a `CancellationToken` that times out after a certain amount of time, there is a [constructor for `CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139229(v=vs.110).aspx) that does just that:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var meResult = await connectClient.GetAsync("me", cts.Token);
```

By the way, even if you don't do this, a .NET thread won't be locked while you wait for `GetAsync` to finish - that's one of the direct benefits of using `await` instead of `.Result`.

Related article by Stephen Toub: [Coalescing CancellationTokens from Timeouts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/03/10244004.aspx)

Comment: May be i didnt express myself properly. My worry is that methodA will be called many times and each time it hang on the await line. I know i can solve it by the cancellationToken, but my question is : if i used the first approach and the method requested many times with no connection, would it cause thread pool depletion? Performance penalty? Thx in advance

Comment: @stackunderflow From the information provided, I can't tell.

Comment: Please advice me  to edit my questin, so it can be answered!!

Comment: @stackunderflow Try to give more context in your question. The problem is that I now don't understand what it is that you're asking, so I'm really unable to advise how to ask it better.

Comment: Forget my scenario above! My question is: if you use await in a method without cancellationToken, there is a possibility that you will keep waiting for ever!!! If your method is going to wait infinitely and this method is requested many times during the app runtime then this will cause performance issue and degradation of resources... Am i correct??

Comment: @stackunderflow Yes that's correct. Anything hanging indefinitely is bad. If the service you are accessing has a chance of being unavailable, you should definitely use the `CancellationToken` approach - that's partly what it's there for!